# XAML thumbnail?

Tags: xaml, thumbnails

Can I create a thumbnail for an xaml content?
Consider that I have a slide-xaml file:Canvas, ScrollView, etc., and I want to create a thumbnail, (like in PowerPoint) and everything I do on my slide(add textBlock, button, etc) to can reflected(view) on my thumbnail.

Regard, 
Andrei.